# Passing a parameter in to a table in report with XPath

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I'm using an xml datasource and passing the xml data to a table in ireport. I have a requirement where the values of the xml tag "amount" needs to be formatted and passed to the table. I have created "amount" as a parameter and passed it from a java class, but all the rows of the table under the amount column is printing the same value.

What I have done is:

```
1. Created a parameter in the subdataset
2. Edited the table datasource and added amount in the parameters tab
```

Please refer the .jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="DCU_New_template" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="540" leftMargin="36" rightMargin="36" topMargin="36" bottomMargin="36" uuid="af5e4276-6e2e-4357-8845-dc8f7d22f777">
    <subDataset name="datasetOne" uuid="ea5d2d96-84ca-46ca-a811-d75e3935428f">
        <parameter name="amount" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/sendDetail/results/]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="results" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="effDate" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[effDate]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="period" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[period]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="amount" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[amount]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="totalAmount" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[totalAmount]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="policyNbr" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="accountId" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="frequency" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[frequency]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="path" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="policyNbr" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="accountId" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="firstName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="lastName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="frequency" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="effDate" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="amount" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="effDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[effDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="period" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[period]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="amount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[amount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="totalAmount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[totalAmount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="accountId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="policyNbr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="frequency" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[frequency]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="285">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="381" y="98" width="130" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Enrollee Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="224" y="98" width="125" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Current Amount Due:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="0" y="99" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Billing Information:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="414" y="48" width="126" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="9" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[deltadentalins.com/aarp]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="0" y="222" width="157" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Recent Transaction History]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="0" y="182" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Billing Frequency:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="0" y="144" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Account Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="157" y="254" width="38" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[From:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="224" y="125" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount Due]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="381" y="163" width="159" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Clearwater,FL 337564115]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="224" y="143" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Due Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="311" y="254" width="23" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[To:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="0" y="163" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="381" y="125" width="159" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[1243 S Martin Luther King Jr]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="381" y="144" width="159" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ave Unit C201]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="68f99313-089f-4856-9b3b-1de9b8141c8e" x="0" y="125" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="13" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Enrollee ID:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement uuid="a647e2c1-3f18-47ed-8bb6-0940492843e2" x="0" y="0" width="334" height="63"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{path}+"aarp_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1600e59d-be63-48cf-a53d-34d663928d09" x="108" y="125" width="100" height="16"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{policyNbr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1600e59d-be63-48cf-a53d-34d663928d09" x="107" y="143" width="100" height="16"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{accountId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1600e59d-be63-48cf-a53d-34d663928d09" x="107" y="163" width="100" height="16"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{firstName}+" "+$P{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1600e59d-be63-48cf-a53d-34d663928d09" x="107" y="182" width="100" height="16"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{frequency}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1600e59d-be63-48cf-a53d-34d663928d09" x="301" y="143" width="100" height="16"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{effDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1600e59d-be63-48cf-a53d-34d663928d09" x="301" y="125" width="100" height="16"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="98">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="80fd2c41-8337-450e-ac79-99a19fcfdc73" key="table 2" style="table 2" x="1" y="0" width="540" height="98"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="datasetOne" uuid="e9aa6c17-781e-41e9-8eb8-79526d0bddb0">
                        <datasetParameter name="amount">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{amount}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/sendDetail/results")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column uuid="66d5e38d-7d0c-4eb6-85f8-52cfd7f240a0" width="82">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="92cfb518-38e4-484e-9a41-a1e5d53927e9" x="0" y="0" width="82" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Invoice Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="78fb6f48-1cd5-4692-817d-f811dd59a570" x="0" y="0" width="82" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountId}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="ff61e14f-5e24-48f4-841c-e8af679fae6c" width="82">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="1933c38d-4a06-4496-8f18-3feec9655960" x="0" y="0" width="82" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Effective Date]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="f0412d18-6093-483f-86d3-aacbd2d47a6f" x="0" y="0" width="82" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{effDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="4d483cce-1bfe-44ed-9533-123f5c01d955" width="137">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="6a1bfbb1-f538-484b-b7ca-dcdb01685b75" x="0" y="0" width="137" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="275b32d5-ce4b-4ef6-b7e3-229b103feadf" x="0" y="0" width="137" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="3448ad87-41d0-4d8e-b760-c9f68c7c9892" width="160">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="44e5026f-aba1-43a5-b357-621e56fdd239" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Billing Period]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="5b71dcac-1142-43ee-90c8-e4ea4a156c1f" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{period}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column uuid="31c4232c-9a4f-47cd-a54b-8ce5f870f783" width="77">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="a787230a-809e-4681-92c0-622b2c3021a1" x="0" y="0" width="77" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Current Amount]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="08a96cb3-dade-496c-884d-f92fc590104e" x="0" y="0" width="77" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

XML File:

```
<sendDetail>    
<results>
    <effDate>2015-10-20</effDate>
    <period>DEC 1;2015 TO FEB 29;2016</period>
    <amount>100.25</amount>
    <totalAmount>184.54</totalAmount>
    <description>Premium</description>
</results>
<results>
    <effDate>2015-10-20</effDate>
    <period>DEC 1;2015 TO FEB 29;2016</period>
    <amount>132.41</amount>
    <totalAmount>0</totalAmount>
    <description>Premium Cancellation</description>
</results>
<results>
    <effDate>2015-07-20</effDate>
    <period>SEP 1;2015 TO NOV 30;2015</period>
    <amount>154.21</amount>
    <totalAmount>0</totalAmount>
    <description>Premium Cancellation</description>
</results>
<results>
    <effDate>2015-07-20</effDate>
    <period>SEP 1;2015 TO NOV 30;2015</period>
    <amount>165.46</amount>
    <totalAmount>177.48</totalAmount>
    <description>Premium</description>
</results>
</sendDetail>
```

Result PDF:
[image]

Comment: 1) The XPath expression at subDataset looks strange - you did not use paramater passed to the jr:table. Are you planning to filter data by `amount`? 2) `all the rows of the table under the amount column is printing the same value` - What does it mean? You should post the generated result

Comment: Thank you Alex! 1. I am not trying to filter data by amount 2. Please refer to the generated result image attached to the query.